MDC not logged when using SLF4J and Log4J2
I'm trying to log MDC using a json formatter in a Wildfly application.  I'm hoping to see all of the MDC keys and their values in each of the logs after setting the MDC values.
I don't want to use Wildfly's logging subsystem as it gives problems with some old 3rd party libraries I'm using (it's a legacy application and replacing those libraries will bee too time consuming at this point)
In order to use my own logging and not Wildfly's, I've set the following in my jboss-deployment-structure:
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.3">
    <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="logging"/>
        </exclude-subsystems>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>

Here is my log4j2.xml configuration:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO" monitorInterval="30">
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="FileJSON" fileName="${sys:log.path}/json.log"
                     filePattern="${sys:log.path}/json.%i.log.zip">
            <JSONLayout eventEol="true" compact="false" stacktraceAsString="true">
            </JSONLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="4"/>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <AsyncRoot level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="FileJSON"/>
        </AsyncRoot>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>

Here is a snippet of how I would use MDC:
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.slf4j.MDC;

...
public class MyClass {
      private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);

  public void someMethod() {
     MDC.put("transaction.id", "123");
     MDC.put("transaction.user", "joe");

     LOGGER.info("Starting transaction");
  }
} 

What I get in my logs, is something like this:
{
  "instant" : {
    "epochSecond" : 1718129460,
    "nanoOfSecond" : 6224000
  },
  "thread" : "EJB default - 1",
  "level" : "INFO",
  "loggerName" : "com.MyClass",
  "message" : "Starting transaction",
  "endOfBatch" : false,
  "loggerFqcn" : "org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger",
  "threadId" : 211,
  "threadPriority" : 5
}

What I was hoping to get:
{
  "instant" : {
    "epochSecond" : 1718129460,
    "nanoOfSecond" : 6224000
  },
  "thread" : "EJB default - 1",
  "level" : "INFO",
  "loggerName" : "com.MyClass",
  "message" : "Starting transaction",
  "endOfBatch" : false,
  "loggerFqcn" : "org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger",
  "threadId" : 211,
  "threadPriority" : 5,
  "mdc":{
     "transaction": {
        "id": "123", "user": "joe"
     }
   }

or even
  "mdc":{"transaction.id": "123", "transaction.user": "joe"}
}

When I use the Jboss logging system, this works, but due to a third party library that does weird things with the logger and causes class cast exceptions involving JBossLoggerContext in that library, I have given up on this path and am now trying to just use my own log4j configuration.
For reference here are my maven dependencies:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j2-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
        </dependency>



Do you have log4j-slf4j2-impl on your classpath? log4j-core is not an SLF4J implementation, so you need a bridge from SLF4J to Log4j 2 API. log4j-over-sff4j is a bridge from Log4j 1 to SLF4J.

Yes, I'll update the issue to show that.

I found the solution for my problem.  I had to add properties="true" to the JSONLayout tag:
<JSONLayout eventEol="true" compact="false" stacktraceAsString="true" properties="true">

It seems that using the newer JsonTemplateLayout is also a better solution.
